# how to get the props value in the following code.I have got the value in the platformstate

Tags: android, react-native, redux

how to get the props value in the following code.I have got the value in the platformstate.But idont understand how we will get data to the baseURL param.I have commented the portion where i want the value

```js
    import axios from 'axios';
    import {ToastAndroid} from "react-native";
    import {connect} from 'react-redux';

    const client = axios.create({
      //want to pass the dynamic value from porps to baseURL
      baseURL: "https://test.xyz.com/",
      headers: { 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache' },
    });

    client.defaults.params = {};
    client.defaults.params['index'] = "test";

    client.interceptors.response.use(
      function (config) {
        return config;
      },
      function (error) {
        ToastAndroid.show('Request failed', ToastAndroid.LONG);
        console.log(error.response);
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );

    //value present in platform state
    function mapStateToProps(state) {
      return {
        platformstate:state.plat.configdata
      }
    }
    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(client)
```

Someone please help!!!!

Comment: @cltsang can you help me in solving this

Comment: I would love to, but you are pretty far off. I suggest reading react and redux documentation first. It looks like you want to export a react component instead of an axios client.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass an arrow function to client, and in that function you can pass the props.

```
const client = (props) => axios.create({
  //and here you can get your required value from props like
  platformstate: props.platformstate,
  baseURL: "https://test.xyz.com/",
  headers: { 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache' },
});
```